# Lightning Platform Quick Access Menu

Tags: lightning-experience

Is there some way to enable Lightning Platform Quick Access Menu.
Salesforce help says as below.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_quick_access_menu.htm&type=5

But another help link says

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_ui_customization.htm&type=5
This menu, with shortcuts to various app and object customization features, is available in Salesforce Classic only.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOTH say that it's only available in Classic.

Comment: Yes can see it says Available in Classic.But i was confused by the name "Lightning Platform quick access menu:"  .Thank you for clearing up